# Why does ParametricPlot does not reach the values I expect?

Tags: plotting, special-functions, parametric-functions, precision-and-accuracy

I have these expressions:

```
vh[m_, γ_] := 
 Sqrt[((γ^2 - 4 EllipticK[m]^2) (γ^2 - 
     4 m EllipticK[m]^2))/(-γ^2 EllipticK[m]^2 + 
   4 (1 + m) EllipticK[m]^4)](*Sqrt[ε0/
  n]*)(EllipticK[m] - 
    EllipticPi[1 + m - γ^2/(4 EllipticK[m]^2), m])

hR[m_, γ_] := 2*Sinh[vh[m, γ]/2]

Areac[m_, γ_] := (
 4 EllipticK[m] (-EllipticE[m] + EllipticK[m]))/ Sqrt[γ^2 - 
  4 (1 + m) EllipticK[m]^2]

FAc[γ_] := α /. 
    FindRoot[-4 (1 + Tan[α]) + γ^2/
       EllipticK[Tan[α]]^2 == 0, {α, -.5}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 50, WorkingPrecision -> 30] // Quiet // 
  Chop(*divergence of the area*)

FBc[γ_] := α /. 
    FindRoot[(2/γ EllipticK[Tan[α]] == 
       1), {α, -1.5}, PrecisionGoal -> 50, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 30] // Quiet // Chop(*x\[Equal]1*)
```

When I evaluate

```
γ = 0.172969;
{hR[Tan[FBc[γ]], γ], Areac[Tan[FBc[γ]], γ]}
```

I get

> ```
> {0., -1.99877}
> ```

so I expect that value in the plot. But when I make a plot with:

```
ParametricPlot[{hR[Tan[α], γ], Areac[Tan[α], γ]}, 
  {α, FBc[γ], FAc[γ]- 0.001 (* to avoid -∞ *)}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-10, -1}}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0.0, -5}, 
  AspectRatio -> 0.7, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

What happened? Why does `ParametricPlot` does not show the point I expect?

Comment: `Ah0` is not defined in your code.

Comment: @MarcoB Sorry, changed `PlotRange`, same problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point you want corresponds to the very first lowest value of $\alpha$; playing around with the values of your expression shows that very small changes in the value of $\alpha$ in this region translate to huge changes in the abscissa of the parametric points you want plotted. In other words, it is extremely easy for the adaptive internal plotting routines `ParametricPlot` to "miss" that point, because it is so far from the others.

You could increase the number of `PlotPoints`, but even ridiculously high values (>1000) get you closer but not all the way there. I think you might be better off constructing your own list of points and plotting it:

```
data = Table[
         {hR[Tan[α], γ], Areac[Tan[α], γ]},
         {α, FBc[γ], FAc[γ], 1/1000}
       ];

ListLinePlot[data]
```

[image: 2D plot from table of values]

---

As an aside, you are using high precision for the rest of the calculations, so do not use `0.001` in your range specification, as this will degrade the precision. Whenever you can, specify any numbers in arbitrary precision (i.e. `1/1000`) instead.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a little on MarcoB's answer, if you want the plot to extend to the point `{0., -1.99877}`, you must tweak the plot options appropriately. Like so:

```
With[{γ = 0.172969},
  ParametricPlot[{hR[Tan[α], γ], Areac[Tan[α], γ]}, {α, FBc[γ], FAc[γ] - 0.001},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-10, -1}},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, Automatic}, Automatic},
    PlotPoints -> 200, (* this is what extends the curve *)
    AxesOrigin -> {-.05, -5},
    AspectRatio -> 0.7,
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    Epilog ->
      {AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{hR[Tan[FBc[γ]], γ], Areac[Tan[FBc[γ]], γ]}]}]]
```

Then you will get a plot that looks like this:

[image: plot]

Answer (score 2):

There's a rounding error at the initial sampling point that causes the x coordinate to become purely imaginary.  One fix is to add `Method -> "BoundaryOffset" -> True`:

```
ParametricPlot[
 {hR[Tan[α], γ], Areac[Tan[α], γ]},
 {α, FBc[γ], 
  FAc[γ] - 0.001 (*to avoid-∞*)},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-10, -1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0.0, -5}, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.7, PlotStyle -> Red,
 Method -> "BoundaryOffset" -> True]
```

[image]

---

**Appendix: Analysis**

The offending input and output values (there are many points and it was easy to spot by eye):

```
ParametricPlot[
     Sow@{hR[Tan[Sow@α], γ], 
       Areac[Tan[α], γ]}, {α, FBc[γ], 
      FAc[γ] - 0.001 (*to avoid-∞*)}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 1.2}, {-10, -1}}, AxesOrigin -> {0.0, -5}, 
     AspectRatio -> 0.7, PlotStyle -> Red] //
    Reap //
   
   Partition[#[[-1, -1]], 2] & //
  #[[4]] & // InputForm
(*
{-1.570553247632789,
 {0. + 8.155582364510667*^-8*I, -1.9987731917946292}}
*)
```

Check `α` and x coordinate:

```
FBc[γ]
(*  -1.57055324763278893087573568762  *)
    
-1.570553247632789 == FBc[γ]
(*  True  *)

{hR[Tan[-1.570553247632789], γ], Areac[Tan[FBc[γ]], γ]}

(*  {0. + 8.15558*10^-8 I, -1.99877}  *)
```

I don't really have an explanation for why there's a rounding error. (On the one hand, it's small, but, in my opinion, it's not small enough.)